# Make a div's background image centered when showing only part of the image?

Tags: html, css, image

So I have a div, in which has a background image.

```
<div id="articles_base" style="background-image:url(http://www.michaeldylanedwards.co.uk/admin/uploads/{page_alias})" style="background-position:center center" width: 235px; height: 240px;>
```

So what I need to know is instead of the div's background image from starting from the top left, how do I make it to start in the center, and not resize?

Any help, as always, is great :)

Comment: Do you want the image to be centered in the div? Or do you want the top-left corner of the image to be in the center of the div?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with `background-position:center`. But you've got two `style` attributes and some misplaced quotes, which make your HTML invalid.

Also, depending on what you're looking for, you might want to prevent the image from repeating with `background-repeat:no-repeat`.

```html
<div id="articles_base" style="
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/80/abstract/1/');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
```

I recommend using a CSS definition rather than inline styles, like the demonstration below:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/80/abstract/1/');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, although I would prefer it to be on the actual index, is there a way to make it do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "actual index". If you want the styles to be inline, please note that I've edited my answer for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm reading your question is that you want the **top left corner** (i.e. the start) of your image to be in the center of your div, correct?

Since your image has a known size (235px by 240px), you can use `background-position` to set a position for the top left corner of your background like this:

```
background-position: 117px 120px;
```

Comment: I mean say if I have a div 100 x 100, then an image of 200 x 200, I want the center of the image to be the center of the background image on the div, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
background-position: center center;
background-position: 50% 50%;
```

Works too ;-)